# Need help in writing SQL query

Tags: sql, select, join

Table - **Products** has number of products as below

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════╗
║ PRODUCTID ║ PRODUCTNAME ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╣
║         1 ║ Nokia       ║
║         2 ║ Samsung     ║
║         3 ║ BlackBerry  ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╝
```

Table - **SalesPersonProduct** has the below records

```
╔═══════════════╦═══════════╗
║ SALESPERSONID ║ PRODUCTID ║
╠═══════════════╬═══════════╣
║ S1            ║         1 ║
║ S1            ║         2 ║
║ S1            ║         3 ║
║ S2            ║         1 ║
║ S3            ║         2 ║
╚═══════════════╩═══════════╝
```

Write a SQL query that returns the total number of sold products?

Comment: Awesome table display!  How did you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be pretty straight forward. You need first to join both tables. The query below uses `LEFT JOIN` because it includes all the records on the *lefthand side* table which is `Products` even if it has a matching record or none in the *righthand side* table which is `SalesPersonProduct`.

After the records has been joined, you can now use `COUNT()` which is an *aggregate function* to count the number of records for each group.

Since the query is using `LEFT JOIN`, all the records that has no matching record on table `SalesPersonProduct` will have a value of `zero` on the column `TotalSold`.

```
SELECT  a.ProductID,
        a.ProductName,
        COUNT(b.ProductID) TotalSold
FROM    Products a
        LEFT JOIN SalesPersonProduct b
            ON a.ProductID = b.ProductID
GROUP   BY  a.ProductID,
            a.ProductName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1def8/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════╦═══════════╗
║ PRODUCTID ║ PRODUCTNAME ║ TOTALSOLD ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╣
║         1 ║ Nokia       ║         2 ║
║         2 ║ Samsung     ║         2 ║
║         3 ║ BlackBerry  ║         1 ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╩═══════════╝
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to return the total number fo sales, then you can easily do this by counting the rows in the `SalesPersonProduct` table:

```
select count(productid) TotalProducts
from SalesPersonProduct;
```

But if you want the total number of sales for each product, then you will need to `JOIN` the tables on the `productId` column:

```
select p.productname, count(s.productid) TotalSales
from products p
left join SalesPersonProduct s
  on p.productid = s.productid
group by p.productname
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bb9c8/2).

In the `JOIN` version, I close a `LEFT JOIN` which will return all product names, even if there are no sales for it.  In your sample data, if you added Apple as a product name, then you would return the following result with a LEFT JOIN:

```
| PRODUCTNAME | TOTALSALES |
----------------------------
|       Apple |          0 |
|  BlackBerry |          1 |
|       Nokia |          2 |
|     Samsung |          2 |
```